# How to split String in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split a string using a T-SQL query without creating any function or stored procedure.

For example I have a string like

```
"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"
```

Now I want get value for `Job Type` which is `New`.

Please suggest me any way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions. You can use the former to split up the string at a certain character position and the latter to search the string for a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

<del>This should work, but it will depend on the order of the attributes:</del>

```
select  substring(@string, charindex('Job Type', @string) + 17, charindex('Proof Number', @string) - 82)
```

<del>I tested this with other values for "Job Type" and it seems to work pretty well.  If the order of your attributes changes this procedure will no longer work though...</del>

Scratch all that - if the value of of the first attribute changes that will no longer work... The following should handle any size values:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = '"Attribute "Request Type" value: asdfasdf; Attribute "Job Type" value: ReallyLongString; Attribute "Proof Number" value: BiggerValue; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"'

declare @stringToUse varchar(max) = substring(@string, charindex('Job Type', @string), charindex('Proof Number', @string))

select  @stringToUse

select  charindex('Job Type', @stringToUse)

select  charindex('Proof Number', @stringToUse)

select  substring(@stringToUse, charindex('Job Type', @stringToUse) + 17, charindex('Proof Number', @stringToUse) - 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
GO

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @str = '"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"';

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('JOB TYPE', @str) + 17, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('JOB TYPE', @str) + 17), 1, CHARINDEX('Attribute', @str) + 1);
```

(OR)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"',CHARINDEX ('JOB TYPE','"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"')+17,LEN('"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"')-CHARINDEX ('JOB TYPE','"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"')+17),1,CHARINDEX ('Attribute','"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in one query then you can use following CTE approach, but it is heavily hard coded, you can improve it for dynamic use:

```
DECLARE @List       NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;'
DECLARE @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255) = N';'

DECLARE @ll INT = LEN(@List) + 1, @ld INT = LEN(@Delimiter);

   WITH a AS
   (
       SELECT
           [start] = 1,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll),
           [value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(
                        SUBSTRING(@List, 1, 
                        COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                        @List, 1), 0), @ll) - 1)
                        , 'Attribute', '')))
       UNION ALL

       SELECT
           [start] = CONVERT(INT, [end]) + @ld,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll),
           [value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(
                    SUBSTRING(@List, [end] + @ld, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll)-[end]-@ld)
                       , 'Attribute', '')))
       FROM a
       WHERE [end] < @ll
   )
   SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            REPLACE([value],'"Job Type"', '')
            , 'value', ''),':','')
            ))
   FROM a
   WHERE LEN([value]) > 0 AND [value] LIKE '%Job Type%'
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

But I must encourage you to use UDF to convert your string into table and then to consume it.
Original idea has been taken from [Common Table Expression](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for the other attributes, just change the where statement.

Rework your data as XML:

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(max) =
  '"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"' 

SELECT 
  RIGHT(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'), 
    PATINDEX('%_ :eulav%', REVERSE(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)'))))
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
      REPLACE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(@txt), 1,2, '')), 1, 1, '; '), 
        '; Attribute ', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)
WHERE t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)') like  '"Job Type"%'
```

Result:

```
New
```

Answer (score 0):

Its safer to split Semi-column separated values to new rows.

[image]

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(MAX)='"Attribute "Request Type" value: Prior; Attribute "Job Type" value: New; Attribute "Proof Number" value: 1; Attribute "Vision Number" value: 534290;"'
-- You can pass your desired Attribute to get the value
DECLARE @ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR(100)='Job Type'

-- Extracts the value after the semi column
SELECT Ids,RIGHT(Ids,LEN(Ids)-CHARINDEX(':',Ids)) VALUE 
FROM
(   -- Converts the Semi column seperated values to rows
    SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),'"',''),1) 'Ids' 
    FROM  
    (
         -- Select the string in XML format
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@STR, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data         
    ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)

)TAB
WHERE Ids LIKE '%Attribute%' AND Ids LIKE '%'+@ATTRIBUTENAME+'%'
```

- **[See the working FIDDLE here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d40a9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Here my simple solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMakeTableFromList](
  @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimiter  VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT
         Item =
           CONVERT(
             VARCHAR,
             Item)
        FROM
         (SELECT
           Item =
             x.i.value(
               '(./text())[1]',
               'varchar(max)')
          FROM
           (SELECT
             [XML] =
               CONVERT(
                 XML,
                 '<i>' +
                 REPLACE(
                   @List,
                   @Delimiter,
                   '</i><i>') +
                 '</i>').query('.')) AS a
           CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS y
        WHERE
         Item IS NOT NULL);
GO
```

The function literally takes a string, delimited by a space or some other character and converts it into a functional table object, which you can use in your own queries. Since SQL does not have an "array" object as such, the **table** is the *array*.

In newer SQL you only need the [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.